# Multimedia computing

Tags: multimedia

I was looking for a solution to the below question, any help provided will be highly appreciated.

Generate a gray-scale image of size 256 x 256 in an array by using random integers in [0, 15]. Use 4 x 4 dither matrix to display the dithered image using binary intensity (i.e. Zero intensity or maximum intensity). Display the original image (the one generated using random numbers) and the dithered image.

Comment: Have you actually attempted to do your own work, or do you just want someone else to do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

The following Forth program for [Gforth](https://gnu.org/software/gforth/) creates a random grayscale image with 15 levels, dithers it with a 4×4 index matrix into a bilevel image, copies both side by side into a 512×256 byte array, and writes that as PGM image to standard output so it can be piped into `display` from the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) package:

```
include random.fs

256 constant image-size
15 constant max-gray-value

create grayscale-image  image-size dup *  chars allot
create result-image  image-size dup * 2*  chars allot
create index-matrix   0 , 12 ,  3 , 15 ,
                      8 ,  4 , 11 ,  7 ,
                      2 , 14 ,  1 , 13 ,
                     10 ,  6 ,  9 ,  5 ,

: randomly-fill-grayscale-image  ( -- )
    image-size dup *  0
    ?do
        max-gray-value random  grayscale-image i chars +  c!
    loop
;

: copy-grayscale-to-result-image  { offset -- }
    image-size 0
    ?do
        grayscale-image  i image-size * chars +
        result-image  i image-size 2* *  offset +  chars +
        image-size
        move
    loop
;

: dither-grayscale-image ( -- )
    image-size 0
    ?do
        image-size 0
        ?do
            grayscale-image  j image-size * i + chars +  dup  c@
            index-matrix  j 4 mod 4 *  i 4 mod  +  cells +  @
            < if 0 else max-gray-value then
            swap c!
        loop
    loop
;

: print-pgm ( -- )
    ." P5" cr
    image-size dup 2* 2dup . . max-gray-value . cr
    * result-image swap type
;

: main  ( -- )
    utime drop seed !
    randomly-fill-grayscale-image
    0 copy-grayscale-to-result-image
    dither-grayscale-image
    image-size copy-grayscale-to-result-image
    print-pgm
;

main bye
```

This can be called as:

```
$ gforth dither.fs | display
```

If `display` is not available the image can be redirected into a file and viewed with another image viewer or editor:

```
$ gforth dither.fs > dither_image.pgm
```

The resulting image looks like this:

[image: Random and dithered image side by side]